# Функции Kotlin в Javascript

Tags: javascript, kotlin

Какие есть аналоги apply в javascript? Создал объект:

```
const button = {
title: "",
setTitle(text){
    this.title = text
},
render() {
    return `<a href="#" class="button">
    ${this.title}
  </a>`
},
apply(func){
    return func()
}
};
```

Вызываю:

```
button.apply(function() {
            this.title = 's';
            this.render();
        })
```

Но пишет, что render это не функция. Что не так? Как правильно реализовать подобное?

Comment: Вы типа такого хотели реализовать: apply(title){
    return this.render(title);
}
Вызывать: button.apply("s") ?

Comment: Нет. Хотел как в Kotlin: element.apply{ title = "title"; id="id"; ... }

Comment: Непонятно, что вы хотите. Напишите подробнее, чего хотите добиться?

Comment: @StepanKasyanenko, чтобы внутри функции apply я мог изменять значения объекта, как в Kotlin.

Comment: как в Kotlin - не очень хорошее описание.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Немного непонятно, что вы хотите. Может, вам нужно это?

```js
const button = {
  title: "",
  setTitle(text) {
    this.title = text
  },
  render() {
    return `<a href="#" class="button">
    ${this.title}
  </a>`
  },
  apply(func) {
    return func.apply(this);
  }
};

button.apply(function() {
  this.title = 's';
  console.log(this.render());
})
```